# How to deal with a swap file error from the 'git commit -a' command?

Tags: git, bash, vim, git-commit

I'm currently working on git hub and I'm in my elementary stage practising how to control files.

The following is my current status:

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   index.html

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Now I'm trying to commit modifications using the `git commit -a` command.

But as soon as I type `git commit -a`, the bash shell shows something like:

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name "~/Desktop/ComputerScience/GitHub/.git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp"
      owned by: choehyeong-gyu   dated: Sun Mar 12 22:31:25 2017
     file name: ~choehyeonggyu/Desktop/ComputerScience/GitHub/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
      modified: YES
     user name: choehyeong-gyu   host name: choehyeong-gyuuiMacBookPro.local
    process ID: 6651
While opening file "/Users/choehyeonggyu/Desktop/ComputerScience/GitHub/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG"
         dated: Sun Mar 12 22:41:36 2017
  NEWER than swap file!

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r /Users/choehyeong-gyu/Desktop/ComputerScience/GitHub/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG"
to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
If you did this already, delete the swap file "/Users/choehyeong-gyu/Desktop/ComputerScience/GitHub/.git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp"
to avoid this message.

Swap file "~/Desktop/ComputerScience/GitHub/.git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

I was unprepared for this, and just entered 'E'. Then, the shell shouts out,

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name     "~/Desktop/ComputerScience/GitHub/.git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp"
      owned by: choehyeong-gyu   dated: Sun Mar 12 22:31:25 2017

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#       modified:   index.html
#
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
"~/Desktop/ComputerScience/GitHub/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG" 7L, 209C
```

Now nothing's working and I do not know how to take my next step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is Vim, not Git

This is not a problem with Git, but rather it is caused by the Vim editor. The file it is complaining about is known as a "swap file".

### What is a swap file?

Vim uses a swap file for various purposes, and these files follow the format

```
.{original_filename}.swp
```

So by default, if you are editing a file `COMMIT_EDITMSG`, then a swap file will be created named `.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp`. That in itself is normal. Generally when Vim exits, it cleans these files up.

But if Vim loads a file and finds, when it tries to create a swap file, that one already exists, it gives you this warning and asks how to proceed. This is to protect the user from themselves - Vim assumes that there are two editors open on the same file, which can lead to one overwriting the other's changes, and losing work.

There are a few ways this can happen.

1. You have multiple editors open editing the same file.
2. Someone else is editing the file too.
3. A previous instance of vim crashed while editing this file, and did not clean up the swap file after itself.

### What's with that commit message?

The text that has been loaded into your commit message is just a side-effect of Vim's complaining. Just delete that text and write your own commit message.

### How to fix this

If you are reasonably sure that you or another person are not legitimately editing the file in another session, then the simplest way to solve this is to remove the swap file and it should resolve the problem.

```
rm -f ~/Desktop/ComputerScience/GitHub/.git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp
```